# How to split path in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, split, path

`E:\Web Developmet\Node\Project Management\public\uploads\profile\NCC-Nepal.png`

this is the path and i want it to be

`uploads\profile\NCC-Nepal.png`

how can i do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression for this it could be:

```
RegExp('\uploads\\profile\\NCC-Nepal.png((\/.)|())')
```

Then reassign the current path with the result of RegEx.

Comment: This RegExpression no, but you can make some which will work for dynamic path if you learn how to use Regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .split() or Regular Expression. But what if the path is dynamic ?

How did you get this (below path) in the first place ?

E:\Web Developmet\Node\Project Management\public\uploads\profile\NCC-Nepal.png

Maybe if you use node.js "path" module, you may get the below required path in a better way.

uploads\profile\NCC-Nepal.png

Comment: thanks for the response! i am new to it! basically i am trying to load profile picture or say avatar on navbar of dashboard. so it will be dynamic as per user.  here my moto was to pass the image name through express-session. but as you know  i just need the public directory path in order to display the image.